# Difference between minutes

Tags: java, time

Say I have 2 strings in the following format:

"09/21 10:06AM"
"09/21 10:10AM"

How do I find the time difference between these strings, stored as an int? This has to be robust enough to handle situations like 10:59AM and 11:02AM (odd number of minutes in between), 11:59AM and 12:03PM (AM to PM switch) etc. No need to worry about seconds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest:

- Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in API; it's *much* nicer.
- Parse into [`LocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) values
- Find the difference between them with:

  ```
  Minutes period = Minutes.minutesBetween(first, second);
  int minutes = period.getMinutes();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

1. [DateFormat.Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450629/java-equivalent-to-nets-datetime-parse)
2. [Calculate difference between dates](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/DateDifferent.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Parse the strings to `Date` objects and get the difference between them in milliseconds. Then convert those milliseconds to minutes (divide by 60000 and take the ceiling of the result).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a switch to daylight savings the difference can be an hour more on one day than another.

It best to use a library which does this already.  JodaTime is best, but SimpleDateFormat and Date will probably do what you need.

Answer (score -2):

1. Convert the 2 Strings to Dates.
2. Subtract one from the other.
3. Multiply the result by 1440 (Number of minutes in a day).
4. Round the result to an Integer.

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Why the last line?  If you're not going to 'warranty' your answer, maybe not posting it would be a better choice.