# Returning time in minutes

Tags: java

I am trying to find difference between 2 times in minutes with following code.not providing complete code:

```
   String dateStart = "03/25/2014 18:03:00";

String dateStop = "03/25/2014 19:45:00";


SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date d1 = null;

Date d2 = null;



d1 = format.parse(dateStart);

d2 = format.parse(dateStop);    


long diff = endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime();

long minutes = diff/(60*1000) % 60;
```

not sure why it is returnung 14 minutes. instead 102 minutes.

Regards,
chaitu

Comment: why downgrade to this question, what is wrong here

Comment: Post compilable code please.

Comment: are you sure you know what `%` does ?

Comment: posted complete code please check

Comment: what is wrong with '%'. can you let me know what do you know about that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the duration of difference between two dates in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: just i was not asked question here, tried sevral ways and posted question.

Comment: @user3457336 Remove your modulo (`%`) operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501311/difference-between-minutes)

Comment: @user3457336 : what is wrong with it is that `<anything> % 60` can **never** be more than 60, by definition. a fortiori not 102.

Comment: (also, this does 42 or 18, depending on which you consider the start and the end, but never 14. I don't know where you got that from)

Comment: There's no way it returning 14! I think you mean 42.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long diff = endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime();
```

makes diff the difference between the two times in milliseconds (6120000). To get seconds, divide by 1000 (6120). To get minutes, divide the result of that by 60 (102).

To get utter nonsense, further take mod 60 (gives 42).

(Note that this is a mathematical error, not really a question about Java.)

Comment: Good explaintation thank you. my bad, i didn't notice. It gave me correct value till the difference is 59 minutes. after that it failed.

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), use the [Minutes](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html) class. Basically one line of code, calling `minutesBetween`.

### Example Code

Here is some example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

#### Parsing those strings

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" ).withZone( timeZone );
DateTime start = formatter.parseDateTime( "03/25/2014 18:03:00" );
DateTime stop = formatter.parseDateTime( "03/25/2014 19:45:00" );
```

#### Calculating minutes between

```
int minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween( start, stop ).getMinutes();
```

#### ISO Duration (Period)

Or you may want to generate a string in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of [Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. To do so in Joda-Time, use the [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class (yes, date-time terminology is not standardized, used differently by different folks).

```
Period period = new Period( start, stop );
String output = period.toString();
```

#### Results

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "start: " + start );
System.out.println( "stop: " + stop );
System.out.println( "minutes: " + minutes );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
```

When run…

```
start: 2014-03-25T18:03:00.000+01:00
stop: 2014-03-25T19:45:00.000+01:00
minutes: 102
period: PT1H42M
```

That output of `PT1H42M` means "one hour and forty-two minutes".

## Time Zone

Your question and code ignored the crucial issue of time zone in parsing those strings. You should almost always specify a time zone.

## java.time

The new java.time package in Java 8 may have similar features as what you’ve seen here with Joda-Time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference **in minutes**, you have can use:

```
long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
```

When you do:

```
long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
```

you are getting the difference **of minutes** between the dates. In other words, you are *only considering minutes*; not hours, nor days...

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operation in your code isn't needed. Remember that the modulus operator gives you the remainder of an operation. If you take out the "% 60;" part of your code, it should work.

Fixed calculation:

```
long minutes = diff/(60*1000);
```

The situation where you'd want to use the modulus operator is if you wanted to express the difference also in units that are greater than a minute, such as hours or days. In this case you'd use the modulus operator to make sure you'd only extract the number of minutes that are less than 60.